# xml communication with process

Tags: network-programming

It is necessary to make the communication between two independent software. Both programs are running processes on one and the same computer. I control the processes of my program, and I can change them as I want.

Everything is available to them. However processes of the first programs I can access via XML message. And the only way. I have instructions on how to do that. Communication is the only access IP address and a defined port.

What really needs to do? To access the specific hardware device, which controls the first program to which I can only access via IP address and as I said over the specified port.

How should I approach the problem? The program controls the hardware device to which the reader software I do not have the right to access any know how to do it. It works only for the first program, SERVER. The program controls the hardware device to which the reader software I do not have a right of access nor do I know how to do it. It works only for the first program, SERVER.

I tried to access it from your development environment, however I managed to only connection to the server IP address and port specified. The operating system on which it is installed my development environment does not recognize the messages and events that occur on the server processes to which I have access.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If the other program's only way to communicate is via XML and you can't change that, then you're out of options I am afraid.

The reason behind it being my that the other party has no other built-in way of communication. It really stops there.